# Pattern For All Printable Special Characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a pattern for all printable special characters. The pattern will be used for filtering string.

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(256) = 'te@st%$#&'   -- input

-- patern for all printable special characters
-- ASCII 33-47, 58-64, 91-96 and 123-126
DECLARE @Pattern NVARCHAR(256)= '%[^ @%$#]%'



WHILE PATINDEX(@Pattern, @String) > 0
SET @String = STUFF(@String, PATINDEX(@Pattern, @String), 1, '')

SELECT @String
```

--current

-- input: 'te@st%$#&'
-- output: '@%$#'

--desired

-- input: 'te@st%$#&'
-- output: '@%$#&'

-- input: 'te@st%$#`~DAS!%^789*()€'
-- output: '@%$#`~!%^*()'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not pure solution with pattern, you can do it with user defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RemoveNonDisplayChars(@pString VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @IncorrectCharLoc SMALLINT, --Position of bad character
        @Pattern          VARCHAR(128)  --Bad characters to look for

 SELECT @Pattern          = '%['
                          + CHAR(0)+CHAR(1)+CHAR(2)+CHAR(3)+CHAR(4)
                          + CHAR(5)+CHAR(6)+CHAR(7)+CHAR(8)+CHAR(9)
                          + CHAR(10)+CHAR(11)+CHAR(12)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(14)
                          + CHAR(15)+CHAR(16)+CHAR(17)+CHAR(18)+CHAR(19)
                          + CHAR(20)+CHAR(21)+CHAR(22)+CHAR(23)+CHAR(24)
                          + CHAR(25)+CHAR(26)+CHAR(27)+CHAR(28)+CHAR(29)
                          + CHAR(30)+CHAR(31)+CHAR(127)
                          + ']%',
        @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @pString)

  WHILE @IncorrectCharLoc > 0
 SELECT @pString          = STUFF(@pString, @IncorrectCharLoc, 1, ''),
        @IncorrectCharLoc = PATINDEX(@Pattern, @pString)
 RETURN @pString
 END
```

More info on this link: [Remove non printable characters](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic860321-338-1.aspx)

If you want to remove all letters, start pattern with: `'%[a-z,A-Z,' + CHAR(0) + ...`